# Passing dependency in allocator

Tags: c++

I've been making interpreter for prototype-based language .

And i found problem i dont know how to solve .
Objects are splited into actual object and object map with slots. Both of them are allocated into heap that is under control of GC.

Implementation of operator new in Object and ObjectMap are practically same:

```
void* Objects::Object::operator new(size_t size) {
    return Universe::getUniverse()->allocateMemory(size);
}
```

Universe is implemented as singleton that contains pointer to other parts of virtual machine (interpreter , object heap etc.).

This design cant be used with unit tests so i wanted to rewrite it into something like this soo i will be able to inject different heap during testing:

```
void* Objects::Object::operator new(size_t size, ObjectHeap* objectHeap) {
    return objectHeap->allocateMemory(size);
}
```

But i found problem.
Object is creating new ObjectMap in constructor (ObjectMap is using same implementation of operator new):

```
Objects::Object::Object(unsigned char numberOfSlots) {
    this->forwadingPointer = nullptr;

    this->objectMap = new Object_Layout::ObjectMap(numberOfSlots);
}
```

Is there any way to pass that injection into allocator for ObjectMap (when i create Object using heap , Object Map created by Object will be in same heap) ?

Comment: I'm not certain as to whether this can be done with straight `operator new`, but I would say it's probably more idiomatic to make these garbage collection allocation calls be factory methods, rather than using `new` to construct managed instances.

Comment: Plain `new` expression will call plain `operator new` function. Placement `new` expression will call placement `operator new` function. Do you want to call placement `new` at the top level of your test code? Do you want this placement `new` to somehow cause all the other `new` expression at all the lower levels to also call that same placement `new` function? I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo so i must create factory methods that will inject dependency into both  Object and ObjectMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok only way to do this is using factory method to create objects

```
Objects::Object* Objects::Object::create(Memory::ObjectSpace* memory, unsigned char numberOfSlots){
  return new(memory) Object(memory, numberOfSlots);
}
```

I will pass memory object that i want use and static method will pass it into allocator and constructor.
Constructor will pass memory parameter into constructor of ObjectMap.

```
Objects::Object::Object(Memory::ObjectSpace* memory, unsigned char numberOfSlots) {
    this->forwadingPointer = nullptr;

    this->objectMap = new(memory) Object_Layout::ObjectMap(memory, numberOfSlots);
}
```

It will be better to add factory method into ObjectMap too.
Thanks to Silvio Mayolo for idea.

Answer (score 0):

This method will allow you to use a custom memory manager for everything in your unit tests.

You can't use `new` inside your custom memory manager or it will cause infinite recursion, though.

universe..hh

```
class Universe
{
public:
    static Universe * getUniverse();
};
```

universe.cc

```
#include "universe.hh"

Universe * Universe::getUniverse() {
    return new Universe;
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "universe.hh"

namespace myalloc {

    class IAllocator
    {
    public:
        virtual void * allocateMemory (size_t size) = 0;
    };

    //
    // Your heap
    //
    class MyAllocator : public IAllocator
    {
    public:
        void * allocateMemory (size_t size) {
            return ::malloc(size); // call your heap allocator (not 'new'!)
        }
    };

    //
    // Unit testing heap
    //
    class DebugingAllocator : public IAllocator
    {
    public:
        enum e_modes {
            e_alloc, // 0 will get memory
            e_bad_alloc
        };
        void setMode (int m) { _mode = m; }
        void * allocateMemory (size_t size) {
            void * buf {nullptr};
            switch (_mode) {
            case e_bad_alloc:
                throw std::bad_alloc();
                break;
            case e_alloc:
            default:
                buf = ::malloc(size); // my testing allocator
                break;
            }
            return buf;
        }
    private:
        int _mode {0};
    };

    class MyAllocatorHandler {
    public:
        static void setAllocator (IAllocator * allocatorMock) {
            _allocator_ptr = allocatorMock;
        }
        static IAllocator * getAllocator () { return _allocator_ptr; }
    private:
        static MyAllocator _allocator;
        static IAllocator * _allocator_ptr;
    };

    MyAllocator MyAllocatorHandler::_allocator;
    IAllocator * MyAllocatorHandler::_allocator_ptr {&MyAllocatorHandler::_allocator};

} // end namespace myalloc


#ifdef UNIT_TEST
void * operator new (size_t size) {
    std::cerr << "Debug new operator. Alloc " << size << " bytes." << std::endl;
    return myalloc::MyAllocatorHandler::getAllocator()->allocateMemory(size);
}
void operator delete (void * buf) {
    std::cerr << "Debug delete operator." << std::endl;
    ::free (buf);
}
#endif

int main ()
{
    // create a unit test allocator
    myalloc::DebugingAllocator da;
    // change allocator to simulate error conditions
    myalloc::MyAllocatorHandler::setAllocator (&da);

    // no failure for allocation
    Universe * univ = Universe::getUniverse();

    // set failure mode
    da.setMode (myalloc::DebugingAllocator::e_bad_alloc);
    
    try {
        // it will fail even in other libraries...
        //std::string str ("This is a long sentence to avoid small buffer optimizations.");
        
        std::cout << "Try to allocate." << std::endl;
        Universe * univ1 = Universe::getUniverse();

        // we aren't going to arrive here in UNIT_TEST mode
        std::cout << "Can't we see this?"
                  << std::endl;
        delete univ1;
    } catch (std::bad_alloc & ex) {
        std::cerr << "Bad alloc, as expected." << std::endl;
    }

    delete univ;
    return 0;
}
```